# Async.Start vs Async.StartChild

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Assuming `asyncSendMsg` doesn't return anything and I want to start it inside another async block, but not wait for it to finish, is there any difference between this:

```
async {
    //(...async stuff...)
    for msg in msgs do 
        asyncSendMsg msg |> Async.Start
    //(...more async stuff...)
}
```

and

```
async {
    //(...async stuff...)
    for msg in msgs do 
        let! child = asyncSendMsg msg |> Async.StartChild
        ()
    //(...more async stuff...)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The key difference is that when you start a workflow with `Async.StartChild`, it will share the cancellation token with the parent. If you cancel the parent, all children will be cancelled too. If you start the child using `Async.Start`, then it is a completely independent workflow.

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the difference:

```
// Wait 2 seconds and then print 'finished'
let work i = async {
  do! Async.Sleep(2000)
  printfn "work finished %d" i }

let main = async { 
    for i in 0 .. 5 do
      // (1) Start an independent async workflow:
      work i |> Async.Start
      // (2) Start the workflow as a child computation:
      do! work i |> Async.StartChild |> Async.Ignore 
  }

// Start the computation, wait 1 second and than cancel it
let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(main, cts.Token)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)    
cts.Cancel()
```

In this example, if you start the computation using `(1)`, then all work items will finish and print after 2 seconds. If you use `(2)` they will all be cancelled when the main workflow is cancelled.

Comment: Is there any difference with respect to whether the workflow will start on a new thread vs. a threadpool thread?

Comment: Ok, cool, that's what I guessed but wanted to make sure it was the only difference. Thanks

Comment: @ildjarn I have not tested or checked this, but I think the starting mechanism is the same - AFAIK, it will be queued in the thread pool in both cases (`StartImmediate` starts work on the _current_ thread).

Comment: @ildjarn Yes - they are the same. They both use an internal `queueAsync` primitive under the cover (see https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1852 and https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1199)