# Return started Async<T> in F# function from calling a non-async Func<T> from C#?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, c#-to-f#, computation-expression

Let's say I want to call, from F#, this C# function:

```
public static class Foo {
    public Bar Baz()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The problem is this function is CPU intensive and I don't want to block on it. Unfortunately the C# library doesn't have an `Task<Bar> BazAsync()` overload.

Then I want to provide the asynchronous version myself, by creating an F# function that calls it and returns an (already started) `Async<Bar>`. That is, I don't want to use `System.Threading.Task<Bar>`.

I guess what I'm looking for is the equivalent of `Task<T>.Run()` in the F# Async way of doing things.

I've already looked at the following options:

- `Async.StartAsTask` -> deals with C#ish Task type.
- `Async.Start` and `Async.StartImmediately` -> receive `Async<unit>` not `Async<T>`

Is `Async.StartChild` what I'm looking for?
If yes, it would be:

```
let BazWrapper() =
    let asyncTask: Async<Bar> = async {
        return Foo.Bar()
    }
    Async.StartChild asyncTask
```

However, if this above is the solution:

1. Why most documentation around F# async workflows doesn't mention StartChild?
2. Why BazWrapper returns `Async<Async<Bar>>` instead of `Async<Bar>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BazWrapper returns `Async<Async<Bar>>` because that's what StartChild does: it takes an `Async<'T>` and returns `Async<Async<'T>>`. The intent is to use it within an async computation expression, so that you can launch multiple "child" asyncs. Example from the [Async.Start vs Async.StartChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284209/async-start-vs-async-startchild) sample code:

```
async {
    //(...async stuff...)
    for msg in msgs do 
        let! child = asyncSendMsg msg |> Async.StartChild
        ()
    //(...more async stuff...)
}
```

When you're inside an `async` computation expression, the `let!` keyword will "unwrap" an `Async<'Whatever>` leaving you with a value of type `'Whatever`. In the case of calling `Async.StartChild`, the `'Whatever` type is specifically `Async<'T>`.

Therefore, if you want to return an *already-started* async via `Async.StartChild`, the way to do it would be:

```
let BazWrapper() =
    let asyncTask: Async<Bar> = async {
        return Foo.Bar()
    }
    async {
        let! child = Async.StartChild asyncTask
        return! child
    }
```

However, I suspect that you'll find that an already-started async isn't as useful to you as a "cold" async (one that isn't started yet), because a "cold" async can still be composed with other async tasks before starting it. (This can be useful for, for example, wrapping logging around your asyncs.) So if I were writing the code for your situation, I'd probably simply do this:

```
let BazWrapper() =
    async {
        return Foo.Bar()
    }
```

And now BazWrapper() returns an Async that has not been started yet, and you can either start that with `Async.RunSynchronously` if you want the value right away, or use it in other `async` computation expressions.

Comment: ahh, now I can see why `Async<T>` is more flexible than `Task<T>`, and then it seems now a bit ugly to me that the BCL always returns started asynchronous tasks (and this is why initially I thought I should wrap it this way), right?

Comment: Interop with C# functions that expect Tasks is why [`Async.StartAsTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.startastask%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) exists, which returns a `Task<'T>` (an already-started one) which is what C# code will generally expect.

Comment: Wouldn't the already-started version not actually be already started? The only way for a "running" `Async<T> `to exist is with `Async.StartChild`, but it's only pointing to a running `Async<T>` after calling `let! child = ...`. Since you're immediately calling return! on the value, the returned value is simply an unstarted computation that needlessly wraps a computation in a child and immediately waits for it to finish.
The only way I can see to do something equivalent to running a started async is to pass in a "beforeWaiting" function that runs after `StartChild` and before `return! child`